OpenTelemetry not logging in structured json format for Spring Boot application
I have springboot application and I want to log the request/response/headers as single json object as defind below
https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/signals/logs/#structured-logs
Is there any reference implementation for structured logging to captured logs in this format?
https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/signals/logs/#structured-logs
we use loki to push logs to graphana to view it
